# If $X_n \rightarrow X$ almost surely then $f(X_n) \rightarrow f(X)$ almost surely

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Proof: If f is continuous and $X_n \rightarrow X$ almost surely, then $f(X_n) \rightarrow f(X)$ almost surely.

Thats the only information I have.

Does this only hold if the measure on the target space of $f$ is the push-forward measure?

Only hints, please not full solutions.

Comment: If $X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)$ then $f(X_n(\omega)) \to f(X(\omega))$.

Comment: "Does this only hold if the measure on the target space of f is the push-forward measure?" The events $A=[X_n\to X]$ and $B=[f(X_n)\to f(X)]$ are events on *the same probability space* hence no push-forward measure can be involved.

Comment: Cant be f a function to another space?

Comment: Quite unrelated, since, as already said, only the source spaces are involved (and the continuity of f).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
if$$
X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega) \implies f(X_n(\omega)) \to f(X(\omega))
$$
then$$
f(X_n(\omega)) \nrightarrow f(X(\omega)) \implies
X_n(\omega) \nrightarrow X(\omega) 
$$
Now use the monotonicity of measure ($A \subset B \implies \mathbb{P}(A) \leq \mathbb{P}(B)$).

Comment: OP *explicitly* asked not to be given the full solution (which you shouldn't do in any case), and you do just that...

Comment: Ok, I made an edit to correct it.

Comment: "Now use the positivity of the probability mesure" ?? Sorry but I cannot understand what you are talking about.

Comment: @Did: this is the property: $f≥0\implies Ef≥0$. Used on $f(ω)=1_{Xn(ω)↛X(ω)}−1_{f(Xn(ω))↛f(X(ω))}$

Comment: What an extremely intricate way of presenting an extremely simple result...

Comment: Isn't it sufficient to write: $P(\{\omega \in \Omega : f(X_n(\omega))\nrightarrow f(X(\omega))\} )=P(\{\omega \in \Omega : (X_n(\omega))\nrightarrow (X(\omega))\} )=0$ ?

Comment: yes. But you don't have the first equality for sure in the general case.